# How to check user name and password via NodeJs and sqlite?

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I'm trying to check user name and password (which I'm getting via post) and if it correct, response with the user page.

for some reason I'm always fail (although I know the user and pass are correct):

```
app.post("/loginDetials", function(req, res) {

    var userName = req.body.userName;
    var passw = req.body.passw;

    if(req.body.userName && req.body.passw) 
    {
        console.log('Checkking userName: ' + userName + ' password: ' + passw);          
        var db = new sqlite3.Database('usersDataBase'); 
        db.all("SELECT * FROM usersTable where (userName==?) AND (password==?)", function(err,rows){
            if (err)
            {
                console.log('Error: ' + err);
            }
            else
            {               
                rows.forEach(function (row) {
                    console.log('Login Succ')
                    res.sendFile('userSite.html', {root: __dirname })

                });

            }
        });
        db.close(); 
    }  
    console.log('Login Fail')
    res.sendFile('main.html', {root: __dirname })
});
```

What am I doing wrong ?

And is this the correct way to verify details ?

Answer (score 0):

You have some async code and other flow problems with your code.

You are actually sending twice your response and you close the database before the query has been executed.

#### Problem with calling twice `res.send`

```
var userName = req.body.userName;
var passw = req.body.passw;

if(req.body.userName && req.body.passw) {
   /** Some logic */
   res.send(...);
}
res.send(...);
```

So you see `res.send` is called twice if you have supplied `userName` and `passw` query.

#### Problem with async closing db connection

In JavaScript we have async functions which don't stop the flow of the program and rely on callbacks. `db.all` is such a function, which you call and immediately after that you call `db.close()`

```
var db = new sqlite3.Database('usersDataBase'); 
db.all("SELECT * FROM usersTable where (userName==?) AND (password==?)", function(err,rows){

     // You need to move your `db.close()` inside the callback 
     // in order to close the database when the query has ended
     db.close();
     if (err)
     {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
     }
     else
     {               
        rows.forEach(function (row) {
            console.log('Login Succ')
            res.sendFile('userSite.html', {root: __dirname })
        });
     }
});

// db.close();  <-- commented out.
```

Comment: The db.all does not contains the userName and pass as parameters. (Just contains ?). Is it missing ?

Comment: sorry, but how can I transfer the user name and pass as parameters ?